# Desktop Gadget for Things.app?

Tags: macos, things-for-mac

Is there a desktop/dashboard Gadget for Mac Things, the todo application?

Comment: Things is good. Except its name makes it hard to Google :-(

Comment: Are you referring to Things the To Do Application?

Comment: @Chealion: Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are none presently available (although it would be possible to make one given the AppleScript support available in 1.1+).

One possible workaround is to try syncing your Things To Do list with Mac OS X's built in To Do system and use one of the Dashboard widgets available that taps into the built-in To Do system. (eg. [To Do Widget](http://todo.philipefatio.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by desktop gadget but for desktop widgets on OSX you tend to use the Dashboard rather than Desktop. You can access the Dashboard by either using the Dashboard key on an Apple keyboard (usually F3) or F12 on a non-Apple keyboard.

You can download more widgets here: http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/

Comment: It's possible with a preference to drag widgets out of the Dashboard and have them residing on the desktop.